# .Net Core 3.1.5 Class Lib, EF Core 3.1.5 - "Data type 'nvarchar' is not supported in this form"

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm working on a ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app, and other satellite projects. There are some common functions (like auth) I use in all other projects and so I want to implement them in common class lib (.Net Core 3.1 class library). 
The common functions include DB access, so I have to implement EF Core DBContext in the class lib. 
The problem is that there is no Startup.cs in the library, and so I need to instantiate the context manually, like this:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<JWTAuthDataContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
_context = new JWTAuthDataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

Although this is working, but whenever I try to access an entity

```
var users = _context.JWTUser.ToList();
```

I get an error saying:

> "Data type 'nvarchar' is not supported in this form. Either specify
>   the length explicitly in the type name, for example as 'nvarchar(16)',
>   or remove the data type and use APIs such as HasMaxLength to allow EF
>   choose the data type."

The model definition looks like this:

```
[Table("JWTUSER")]
public class JWTUSER
{
    [Key]
    [Column("RECID", TypeName = "bigint")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long RECID { get; set; } // bigint, not null

    [Column("FIRSTNAME", TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string FIRSTNAME { get; set; } // nvarchar(100), not null

    [Column("LASTNAME", TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string LASTNAME { get; set; } // nvarchar(100), not null

    [Column("USERNAME", TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string USERNAME { get; set; } // nvarchar(100), not null

    [Column("DATAAREAID", TypeName = "nvarchar(10)")]
    public string DATAAREAID { get; set; } // nvarchar(10), not null
}
```

I also tried to add fluent API (HasColumnType, HasMaxLength, etc.) in OnModelCreating, without success.

Then I copied the model and the DBContext from the class library to the web app code, and use DI in Startup.cs, then my code is just working as expected. I can query the table and have no error messages.

**UPDATE:** 
I have implemented the missing DI in my class library (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection) and extended IServiceCollection with my extension method.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddJWTAuthCore(this IServiceCollection services, JWTAuthCoreOptions options)
{
    services.AddDbContext<JWTAuthDataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(options.ConnectionString));
    services.AddScoped<AuthService>();
    return services;
}
```

This can be called from the web app Startup, like

```
services.AddJWTAuthCore(new JWTAuthCoreOptions()
{
    ConnectionString = G.ConnectionString
});
```

This is running without error, but still get the same error when I try to access the entity from the library.

What can cause the issue in the class lib while the web app is working well?

Any ide would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to believe - do you have a clean minimal repro? Does your context contain other entities? Note that the exception doesn't mean the problem is in the shown entity - just the db model is built lazily. You shoud get the same exception if you issue `_ = _context.Model;`, don't you? Also have you searched the project files for "nvarchar"?

Comment: @IvanStoev, yes there are more entities, and I found more nvarchar fields annotated differently. Fixed them but still receive the error. My suspect is that nvarchar(max) may cause some trouble. ETHese are annotated like this: [Column("TOKEN", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
        public string TOKEN { get; set; } // nvarchar(max), not null

Comment: Now I changed all TypeName = "nvarchar" to TypeName = "nvarchar(max)" and it is working. Hm... And it answers the question why it was working in the web site: JWTUser entity does not have nvarchar(max) column and I only copied that entity. Thank you for supporting me @IvanStoev. - And you were right, context.Model raised the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:** The problem was that nvarchar(max) columns were annotated as

```
[Column("COLUMN1", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
```

because somewhere I read (unfortunately I cannot recall where, but it must have been an outdated doc) that the default length was MAX if not specified.

The solution immediately started working when I included (max) in the annotation

```
[Column("COLUMN1", TypeName = "nvarchar(max)")]
```